# Optimal way to install ruby on Docker where base-OS access is required?

Tags: ruby, docker

I'm trying to install Ruby on Docker (no Rails), but I'm having some issues. I initially tried with RVM, but I had issues with it; after I'd installed it in the usual way, commands such as `ruby` or `gem install` aren't recognised, and I understand that RVM is not best practice for a docker environment. I tried building from binary, but that seemed to be missing so many essential things, it seemed to be an exercise in futility.

I've now tried using the official docker `ruby:2.5.1` image, however when I attach to this, I get an irb prompt, and am unable to use operating system commands, such as `apt-get` due to this.

It's essential that I have operating system access - this script will be using a browser through headless Watir webdriver, attaching to Geckodriver, so there are a number of dependencies required that won't be included in the base ruby install.

What's the best way to handle this with Docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you on the command-line of the Ruby box:

> docker run -it ruby:2.5.1 bash

You'll now be able to run ruby tools as normal, e.g. `ruby`, `irb`, `gem`. As well as regular Debian commands including `apt-get`.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

If you want to roam around inside a separated environment, you should choose something like Vagrant.

If you are intended to use docker, give a try this approach.
You can place any code in your ruby file whichever you would like to.

```sh
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd)/:/data ruby:2.5 ruby -- /data/hello.rb
  hello world!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've only just learned docker, specifically for this project - going on to learn vagrant will take up too much time at this stage, so it's not an option right now. Thanks though, I'll have a look at it for the future!

I'm not intending to regularly roam around inside the environment. But there are a few core dependencies (e.g. firefox, geckodriver, postgres, xvfb, etc), that do really need to be installed from the Dockerfile. That code isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm already able to run ruby scripts with the ruby image. I need to be able to install things.